# How to scroll to some char in EditText

Tags: android, string, scroll, android-edittext, horizontalscrollview

I have a `HorizontalScrollView` with `EditText` inside. 
`EditText` has text (for example): 
"testing string testing string **X** testing string testing string **Y** testing string testing string test **Z**".
 And i programmatically replace **X** with some string, then i replace **Y** with next some string, etc.
How do i scoll to place, where i replace text:
first: to **X**
second: to **Y**?

i try `addTextChangedListener()` to `myEditText` and on `beforeTextChanged`, `afterTextChanged` get `start`, `end` always `return 0` (becouse i replace programmatically, dont it?).

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My app is calculator and string `"testing string testing string X testing string testing string Y testing string testing string test Z"` is formula.
 And i can wrote every variable position in formula when user create one. So i have all of variables position and can scroll to another one)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, but I think it sounds as if you're wanting to place to cursor after an edit in the place the edit occurred.  If that's what you want, then you can use the Selection methods:

```
        final int selStart = Selection.getSelectionStart(s);
        final int selEnd = Selection.getSelectionEnd(s);
```

Comment: It always `return -1`. What about `end1 = et.getRight()` on `beforeTextChanged` and `end2 = et.getRight()` on `afterTextChanged` and then `end2 - end1` - position to scroll?)

Answer (score 0):

Try use like this:

```
myEditText.scrollTo(x,y);
```

I think this should help.